# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a NSMutableArray that contains a custom class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I receive I EXC_BAD_ACCESS but i can't understand why.
this is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TDBadgedCell *cell = [[[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    SubscriptionArray * element =[reader.subscriptions objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



    [cell.textLabel setText:element.title]; // <--- error at this line of code



    return cell;
}
```

reader.subscritions is NSMutableArray that contains 81 elements ( I'm sure verificated with a NSLog) but when I try to get set the title I have this error... why?
SubscritionArray is a custom class that contains 3 string and 1 int.

Custom class:
header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SubscriptionArray : NSObject{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *source;
    NSString *htmlUrl;
    NSInteger count;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *source;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *htmlUrl;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "SubscriptionArray.h"

@implementation SubscriptionArray
@synthesize title,source,htmlUrl,count;

-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [source release];
    [htmlUrl release];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        title = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"] retain];
        source = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"source"] retain];
        htmlUrl = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"htmlUrl"] retain];
        //count = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"count"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    if (title) [encoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    if (source) [encoder encodeObject:source forKey:@"source"];
    if (htmlUrl) [encoder encodeObject:htmlUrl forKey:@"htmlUrl"];
    //if (count) [encoder encodeInteger:count forKey:@"count"];
}



@end
```

***EDIT***
Tha's what I get
 *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe5a8260

And that's how I set the NSMutableArray

```
subscriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    //make a file name to write the data to using the
    //documents directory:
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/subscriptions", documentsDirectory];
    [subscriptions removeAllObjects];
    subscriptions = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fullFileName];
```

Comment: Can you include your header file for SubscriptionArray? I'm assuming the title property is declared there.

Comment: First thing to do when encountering EXC_BAD_ACCESS is enabling NSZombie.

Comment: I get  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe5a8260

Comment: seems like you have more numbers of cells than objects those are store in the array. What is present in NumberOfRows method?can u put that also here?

Comment: that's my content!  return reader.subscriptions.count;

Answer (score 0):

I'd venture to say that your array of subscription elements isn't matching up with your row indexes (just a guess). Suggest that you set a debugger breakpoint immediately after you've declared 'element' and before you attempt to set the label. You should be able to see if you have actually obtained one of your SubscriptionArray objets...

Comment: Agree here. Could be whatever results you've fetched, could be blank or nil for the title.

Comment: I get  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe5a8260

Comment: Are you using automatic or manual reference counting? It appears you're attempting to access an object that has been released (this could be the mutablearray itself or the object within, but something has been overreleased)...

Comment: Looking at the sample again, looks like you're doing manual management. So I'd go back and look at where you are creating and populating your mutable array. Suggest you comment out any release statements (or disable them systematically one-at-a-time) that refer to your array specifically or to object(s) within.

Answer (score 0):

The mutable array in `reader.subscriptions` is getting deallocated before you attempt to reference it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Make sure that the `subscriptions` array is properly retained or copied by the reader, and that you're not overreleasing it by sending an extra `release` or `autorelease` message somewhere. It might help to post the relevant code from the class of the `reader` instance.